# How to add 1 hour to date Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I have `datetime` `"2016-11-24 11:59:56"`. How can I add one hour to this date and compare it with current datetime?

I tried:

```
$date = "2016-11-24 11:59:56";
$date->addHour();
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to `parse()` it first:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2016-11-24 11:59:56')->addHour();
```

Better way is to add datetime column to a `dates` variable:

```
protected $dates = ['datetime_column'];
```

Then you can just do this:

```
$date = $model->datetime_column->addHour();
```

Answer (score 22):

You can try this:

```
$date = "2016-11-24 11:59:56";
$carbon_date = Carbon::parse($date);
$carbon_date->addHours(1);
```

You can now compare the date using `lt()` & `gt()` methods of Carbon. See [Carbon Comparison Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) for exploring more methods like - `eq()`, `ne()`, `gte()`, `lte()`, etc.

```
$carbon_date->lt(Carbon::now()); // Less then current datetime (returns boolean)
$carbon_date->gt(Carbon::now()); // Greater than current datetime (returns boolean)
```

Hope this helps!